# 1960s Race Car Rear Suspension Question

Tags: suspension, frame, rear-end, racing, suspension-geometry

As you can see in the pictures below they dont have a double wishbone setup but  instead they have this weird setup. Why did they use something like this instead of double wishbones back then and why did they stop using this type of setup afterwards? What were the pros and cons of a setup like this compared to double wishbones?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The upper arms prevent forward and backward movement of the wheel and hub assembly. The lower triangle prevents torsion and toe in/out of the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Many designs have been tried - all to minimise the unsprung weight and improve the response.

And the long tie bars with inboard brakes suggest that, compared to outboard brakes with 2 larger wishbones...